# c# wpf Parallax background image

Tags: c#, wpf, parallax

Please help solve this problem

The problem is that when you move the mouse as moving background, or any other image or
I'm trying to create a parallax effect.

```
Point mouse = e.GetPosition(this);
        TransformGroup group = (TransformGroup)this.bg.RenderTransform; 
        TranslateTransform translate = (TranslateTransform)group.Children[3];
        translate.X = 400 - mouse.X;
        translate.Y = 300 - mouse.Y;
```

My code displays the type of exception: Failed to bring the object type "System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform" to type "System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup".

Maybe someone has the answer to this question?

Comment: When moving the mouse disappears the background. It takes him a slight displacement of the opposite axis

Comment: I don't really understand that kind of effect, the problem mentioned in your question is you need to append a translation to the `RenderTransform` and my code does just that. You should understand how to solve your original problem best. If possible you should ask another question for that in which more info is provided.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is move the mouse along the axis X to the left, the image is slightly shifted to the right. the same thing on an axis Y.